# Is DataGrid and DataTable for WPF not available in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable, visual-studio-2015

I am not able to add DataGrid and Datatable in Visual Studio 2015 UAP project.

Comment: Do you mean WPF or UAP? These are separate technologies.

Comment: what you want to do?